# Compare label text with pickerview row

Tags: ios, uilabel, uipickerview, do-while

I need to compare a text from label with text from pickerview row. I need this to be done in do while loop so I can't use 'isEqual' but something like 'isNotEqual'. I've tried to do it this way:

```
do {
    //something
   } while (Label.text != [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [PickerData objectAtIndex:selected_row]]);
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
while (![label.text isEqualToString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [PickerData objectAtIndex:selected_row]]]);
```

Use NSString methods for string comparisons. Don't use = or != on NSStrings when comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing didSelectRow and getting the value there?

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```